# NuGet - Newbie issue on large enterprise system

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I just inherited a large enterprise system that appears to use NuGet.

I have just read the basics on what NuGet is so pardon the simpleness of my questions.

Is there a way to tell NuGet to update and install all the packages needed to run the system? I am right now running and seeing what fails then guessing what NuGet packages are missing.

(No, there was no documentation in the enterprise system or many code comments, ugh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the package manager console try Update-Package –Project ProjectName

Visual Studio -> Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20All%20Packages

If the solution is configured to enable Nuget Package Restore you could also just delete the packages folder and rebuild all which would get everything that you needed. If you need to worry about javascript, configuration, etc... I would try the Update-Package route

Comment: In addition, if you simply run "Update-Package" (no extra params), you'll update all packages in the solution at once. If you inherited the code base, you might want to take it easy and use the -Safe switch as well..

Comment: @XavierDecoster Do you know if there's a fee to use Nuget in an enterprise environment?

Comment: @Carmine NuGet is opensource and free for all. Not sure what you mean with "a fee to use NuGet in an enterprise environment", but if you are looking for commercial products to facilitate NuGet usage in an enterprise environment, you might want to take a look at www.myget.org, ProGet, or TeamCity. In addition, you could also just use the open source NuGet gallery from github or a simple network share to get started.

Comment: @XavierDecoster Thank you, that explains what I needed to know.  But what I meant by "a fee to use" was that, for example, to use GitHub in an enterprise environment, we have to buy licensing per user, but I didn't know if there was a similar thing in place for Nuget.

Comment: @Carmine to complete your comparison with GitHub: GitHub is Git (and more) as-a-service, whereas MyGet is NuGet (and more) as-a-service. Both Git and NuGet are the core components that you can freely use without "fee" :)